# explode multiple columns of list of dictionaries into pandas dataframe row

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have the below 3 columns of a pandas dataframe. Two of which are list of dictionaries so i want to explode these two columns only for `actor` and `name` key in the dictionaries.

I was trying to do the following manner :

**Code:**

```
 import pandas as pd
    df = (pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Hello', 'World', 'Test'], 
                        'cast': [ [ {"gender": 0, "id": 2423,"actor": "Bruno Delbonnel"},
                                 {"gender": 1, "id": 1234,  "actor": "Alex"} ] ,
                                {"gender": 1, "id": 2424, "actor": "Stuart"},
                                {"gender": 2, "id": 2425, "actor": "Kate"}  ], 
                        'genre': [ {"id": 2343, "name": "magic"},
 [{"id": 616, "name": "witch"}, {"id": 2765, "name": "wizardry"}],                         
                                {"id": 3872, "name": "broom"}] } )
                                .set_index(['name']))

    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    output = []

    _ = df.apply(lambda row: [output.append([row['name'], row['cast']['actor'], row['genre']['name'] ]) 

                                  ], axis=1)

    df_new = pd.DataFrame(output, columns=['name', 'cast', 'genre'])
```

**DataFframe:**

```
  {'name': ['Hello', 'World', 'Test'], 
                        'cast': [ [ {"gender": 0, "id": 2423,"actor": "Bruno Delbonnel"},
                                 {"gender": 1, "id": 1234,  "actor": "Alex"} ] ,
                                {"gender": 1, "id": 2424, "actor": "Stuart"},
                                {"gender": 2, "id": 2425, "actor": "Kate"}  ], 
                        'genre': [ {"id": 2343, "name": "magic"},
                                   [{"id": 616, "name": "witch"}, {"id": 2765, "name": "wizardry"}],
                                {"id": 3872, "name": "broom"}] }
```

**Output:**

```
 name            cast               genre
Hello         Bruno Delbonnel      magic
Hello            Alex              magic
World            Stuart            witch
World            Stuart            wizardry
Test             Kate              broom
```

But since it is a list of dictionaries i was not able to do `row['cast']['actor'], row['genre']['name']`. So, how do achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a function to deal with a list or dictionary element in your series.

Then, to expand your dataframe, repeat or chain items as necessary.

```
from itertools import chain
import numpy as np

def get_val(x, var):
    if not isinstance(x, list):
        return [x[var]]
    else:
        return [i[var] for i in x]

df['cast'] = df['cast'].apply(get_val, var='actor')
df['genre'] = df['genre'].apply(get_val, var='name')

res = pd.DataFrame({'name': np.repeat(df['name'], df['cast'].map(len)),
                    'cast': list(chain.from_iterable(df['cast'])),
                    'genre': list(chain.from_iterable(df['genre']))})

print(res)

              cast     genre   name
0  Bruno Delbonnel     witch  Hello
0             Alex  wizardry  Hello
1           Stuart     magic  World
2             Kate     broom   Test
```

Comment: i am getting this error `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`. reason being there could be a possibility that number of items in `cast ` might not be equal to number of items in `genre`. So, how do you handle that?

Comment: @Naresh, I don't know what you expect in that situation. Do you want empty strings or `NaN` elements when expanding the shorter number of items?

Comment: I want the value of rest of the columns (cast or genre) which are of short length to be repeated just like it is happening in case of name. I have edited the dataframe and output. Could you please look into it.